# How can I import app from another .py file and use app.config in order to use values in config file?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I wann use some values set in config files but Im not sure of how to do that. How should I fix xxx.py ?

This is init file.

```
def init_db(app):
    db.init_app(app)
    Migrate(app, db)


def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
```

xxx.py

```
import create_app
impoet modulename

x = app.config["TOKEN"]
...
...
...
```

config.py

```
Class config:

   TOKEN = 'token'
   ...
   ...
```

Comment: I already looked for the same questions in stackover flow but I could not find. So would you pls share the same question if you knows ?

Comment: You can see the link above your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36435103/access-flask-config-outside-of-application-factory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide `app` object to a call in `xxx.py` as result of `create_app` or make `app` global variable that will be available from anywhere. For example:

```
# __init__.py
def init_db(app):
    db.init_app(app)
    Migrate(app, db)

def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])    
    return app


# xxx.py
import create_app
import module_name

app = create_app('config/path')
x = app.config["TOKEN"]
...
...
```

or

```
# __init__.py
app = None

def init_db(app):
    db.init_app(app)
    Migrate(app, db)

def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])


# xxx.py
import create_app, app
import module_name

create_app('config/path')  # can be called once anywhere in the project
x = app.config["TOKEN"]
...
...
```

Comment: I’d like to use the first one but in app = create_app('config/path'), how should I define path ? Becourse there are three kinds of config and I use one of them deffently depending on environments such as local, development, production.

Comment: I added path as an example because I don't know what you are using. If the first option works good for you - please mark the answer as accepted.